# custom my AlertController swift 3.0

Tags: swift3, uialertcontroller

I'm trying to change the color of the accept button. This is my code.

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Aviso",
                                  message: "¿Desea eliminar el registro?",
                                  preferredStyle: .alert)
//custome dialog
// Restyle the buttons of the Alert
alert.view.tintColor = UIColor.black
alert.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow


// Accept button
let submitAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Aceptar", style: .default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
    self.removePro()
})

    // Cancel button
let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancelar", style: .destructive, handler: { (action) -> Void in })

// Add action buttons and present the Alert
alert.addAction(cancel)
alert.addAction(submitAction)
present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: What I do is write my own presented view controller with a view that _looks_ like an alert controller's view. That way, I can make any customizations I like.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
submitAction.setValue(UIColor.blue, forKey: "titleTextColor")
```